# Submitting file upload field in mongodb using useform react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to submit file upload field as well as all fields to mongodb on click of submit button using useform of react.Please help me i don't know how do using react useform hook

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit broad to meet StackOverflow standards. What is your exact problem? Can you share what did you try to do?

Comment: I want to upload image  in mongodb using useform react